# How to improve my query?

Tags: sql, performance, query-optimization

I need to compute a number through over 150'000 rows (growing) but my query is pretty slow.

Here is the `CREATE TABLE`:

```
CREATE TABLE `device` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `registration_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `creation_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `latest_activity_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_8484BF65454ADE21` (`latest_activity_date`,`status`,`type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=160969 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `article` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `summary` longtext NOT NULL,
  `creation_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `published_date` datetime default NULL,
  `updated_date` datetime default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_A5051EECA76ED395` (`user_id`),
  KEY `IDX_A5051EEC7B00651C9E0806AB` (`published_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20216 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I need to get the number of published Article for each devices given their latest activity date.

So I do :

```
SELECT m.registration_id, COUNT(a.id)
FROM device m, article a 
WHERE (
    m.latest_activity_date < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND
    a.published_date >= m.latest_activity_date AND
    m.status = 'enabled' AND 
    a.published_date <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND (
        m.registration_id <> '' OR 
        m.registration_id IS NOT NULL
    )
) AND m.type = 'foo' 
GROUP BY m.registration_id 
HAVING COUNT(a.id) > 0
```

But this query is a bit slow (over 50 seconds for about ~3000 articles & ~150000 devices)

I tried to `EXPLAIN` but it does not give any clues. I also tried an explicit join (using both `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN ON a.published_date >= m.latest_activity_date` but same result. It also shows that ALL the rows are read an no indexes is used (however it shows IDX_8484BF65454ADE21 as a "possible index").

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not seeing a correlation column (JOIN) between your device and article tables...

Comment: yeah, I posted the "implicit join" here (multilple from clause) but I tried with an explicit join too and I got the same result.

Comment: As to not bloat my current answer... Is it a single device that keeps triggering some "last activity" event? or are there multiple devices, each getting its own activity event.  If so, how far back do you want to allow for ANY device activity might be the better.  How would you otherwise correlate Article X associated with Device A on Jan 18, vs Device B.  Can you post some samples of data from EACH table and show how they SHOULD be correlated and what you would expect out of them... I would say do a dump of about 10 devices and 20 article elements...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to no join condition between the tables, it will basically do a Cartesian join against them (what a mess).

In addition, I would adjust your indexes based best on your criteria of "fixed" values first, then your range of date stuff... to clarify... your

```
WHERE
       m.Status = "enabled" 
   AND m.Type = "foo"
   AND ... other date specific...
```

index on (status, type, dates...)

finally, why so long a field for status and type... these types of fields would be more abbreviated under normal conditions, and at MOST, I would have columns like this as 15-20 characters.  Having index pages with up to 255 characters per field will significantly chew up time in your query too.

Comment: For status/type and all fields which have a small number of possible values, it is better to use type `ENUM`. In that case, mysql stores the data as numbers (so indexes are smaller and faster), and you still get your data as strings.

Comment: @Marki555, I agree, but didn't want to confuse too much.

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer, you suggested an index on (status, type, date) and it's actually what I did : KEY `IDX_8484BF65454ADE21` (`latest_activity_date`,`status`,`type`). I know about that messy cartesian product, but I don't see a way to avoid it.

What's weird is why does my query read ALL rows of the device table where I exclude some with the type & status.

Comment: By the way, the INDEX is not used (showed as POSSIBLE INDEX with EXPLAIN) I read somewhere that indices are not used when the result is up to ~25% of the total number of rows), then I've a big product without using an index, but I don't see how to ride of this

Comment: @Trent, I stil do not see ANY correlation between the tables.. With respect to the index, your sample of latest_activity_date first, but by explicitly having WHERE on status and type, have THOSE in the first positions of the index and the date is the LAST element of the index.  Back to your relationship.  For proper join, there SHOULD be an ID of Device in Article table, or Article ID in the Device table it represents...  Otherwise, your Cartesian will always kill your query.

Comment: @DRapp indeed, but nor my article or my devices are linked. What I need to do is to get for each devices, all articles that has been published AFTER the latest_activity_date.

Example, my device had latest activity on the 21 january, I need to get the count of new published article after the 21 january, I don't see any relationship between both entities.